# Highcharts usage in Electron (npm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts

Being new here and in the Electron/Node World my question concerns the following:

I want to transfer my Webproject into Electron. So far this works perfect without NodeIntegration!
Now I need "node-functionallity", for this reason I installed the official Highcharts npm in my project. This also worked fine - until the highcharts-more.js was required! I always get Highcharts error 17 - https://www.highcharts.com/errors/17

How do I implement this js. as a Module? (e.g in the documentation require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);)) But this doesn't work.
The direct Link  doesn't work either...

Comment: `require('highcharts/highcharts-more)(Highcharts)` should work. Do you have any errors? In your example you load `exporting` so it won't work.

Comment: Yeah! This works! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm the the same situation on an Angular (Typescript) project. Any idea how to load the library?

Comment: well.. just pasted it works! Thanks!!